# Retrieve information from remote computers list

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create Spreadsheet for retrieving information of remote computers list (A:A), by filling only first column with Machine Name and the Service Tag is automatically retrieved.

```
Machine Name | Service Tag
Laptop01     | 
Laptop02     |
```

I just discovered how to execute cmd commands in Excel, but I need help to treat the data.

```
Private Sub btn_WScript_CMD_Click()
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "CMD.EXE /k wmic /node:Laptop01 bios get serialnumber"
End Sub
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613). We need a bit more detailed information about where exactly you got stuck or errors.

Comment: Does this need to happen directly in Excel?  I.e., can you just direct the output of your `wmic` command into a text file and open in in Excel?  Or must it be triggered from within Excel?

Comment: Also, what you're trying to do appears to be discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505486/piping-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-in-vba-to-a-specific-shell/29509003

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Private Sub btn_WScript_CMD_Click()
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    x = WshShell.Run("CMD.EXE /k wmic /node:node:Laptop01 bios get serialnumber > c:\PATH_TO_TXT_FILE", 0, False)
End Sub
```

it creates a text file silently and then you must read it and import the data to Excel.

Comment: Great! With the code I have a text file in c:\hostname.txt with content:


SerialNumber  (line 1)

6LF4VW2 (line 2)


I think I need a loop to get all the A:A items and send to text file only the second line of the command to get only the serial number.

Is it possible to have this result?

Comment: after the WshShell.run, u have to read the file, ignore the first line and get just the second line